# "Missing to call unregisterReceiver" error in wifiManager

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I don't use a Receiver, so I don't register or unregister but when I call a wifiManger method several times, some error is occurring. 
Here is my code:

```
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res);
    boolean es = wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es);
    if (res != -1 && isEdit) {
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(configEdit.networkId);
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
        isEdit = false;
    }
```

Thank you very much all for the help

Error Log:

**Has leaked IntentReceiver android.net.wifi.WifiManager$1@a517b6e that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
```

To

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
```

The way you are doing it can leak the memory

Comment: I tried it but cannot. When I remove  wifiManager.removeNetwork(configEdit.networkId);
wifiManager.saveConfiguration(); error not occur

Comment: Same error: Has leaked IntentReceiver android.net.wifi.WifiManager$1@a517b6e that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?